# Android browser links aren't being redirected to the appropriate application

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-crawlers, android-app-indexing, google-app-indexing

I've implementing Google App indexing on android, my application handles some deep links. So I expect that appropriate links from browser should be redirected to my app. But that doesn't happen. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You should configure the links that want to be opened with your app, correctly.
Usually, you should add the following to your activity/service declaration in the AndroidManifest

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

            <data
                android:host="yourdomain"
                android:path="/yourpath/"
                android:scheme="yourscheme"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Now the urls that start with "yourscheme" will be directly delivered to your activity, throughout an intent.

You can find more about deep linking [here](http://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html).

Comment: I have the correct intent-filters, I can open my app using adb and appropriate deep link. I guess I found the issue, from mobile phone I should explicitly set "always open links" from app settings. But why doesn't this happen automatically. Or system asks it during install?